# Trying to edit a Quick Launch with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, language

I'm trying to edit a Quick Launch title using PowerShell.

I'm using the following

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://www.sharepoint.com/
$ql = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.Children | Where { $_.Title -eq 'Node Name'}
$ql.title = 'New Title'
$ql.Update()
```

This worked fine for me on an English site. When I tried doing this on a site with the French language pack applied the title parameter changed but I could not see the change on the site.

Is there something I'm missing that needs to be changed with language packs?

Comment: Hum, I did this times ago, but I don't remember I got problems. Must be an idiot idea, but did you do a good refresh ? (close/open browser)

Comment: Just tried it in a new browser and same thing. The $ql.title parameter looks changed when I view it but the actual site shows no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try the following (found [here](http://suryapulipati.blogspot.fr/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-update-spnavigationnode.html))
Please note the differences : You get your node in `$LibraryNode`, but you also get the previous node (here: "Home"). Then you use this [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.aspx).

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://www.sharepoint.com/
$navigationNode=$web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
$LibraryNode = $navigationNode | where { $_.Title -eq "Node Name" }
$HomeNode= $navigationHomeNode | where { $_.Title -eq "Home" }
$NewTitle= "Libraries"
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.SPNavigationSiteMapNode]::UpdateSPNavigationNode($LibraryNode, $HomeNode, $NewTitle, $LibraryNode.Url, "", "", "", $true)
$web.Dispose()
```

Let me know if this works.

PS1: you can also refer to that [site](http://www.sharepointkevin.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=48). It's telling the same thing, but maybe its more clear.

Comment: It almost worked. You forgot to define the $NavigationNode
Line 2 should be:

    $navigationNode=$web.Navigation.QuickLaunch



And I set the last input into the UpdateSPNavigationNode method to $true.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to avoid this and forgot to copy/paste ;) Edited. Glad it helps